# Azure function (Time trigger) is triggering only when opening the Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a Time trigger Azure function, which is triggered in 2 Hrs of interval. Every time I open the Azure portal, it is triggered and after that, it is not getting triggered.

I have searched a few links in Google but didn't get any suitable solution. Can anyone please help me out?

```
[FunctionName("MailFailureFucntion")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/30 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)  
{

 // my code - connecting SQL and send mail

}
```

Initially I have tried with `0 */2 * * *` - 2 Hrs interval. Then I have tried with `*/30 * * * *`

Comment: May you please share your time trigger schedule expression?

Comment: Can you please post the function signature and it's CRON expression

Comment: updated with code.

Comment: I think it should be `0 0 */2 * * *` to run for every two hour. Notice there are six placeholders; but in your scenario I see only five.

Comment: The same cron expression is suggested by user Andriy in his answer.

Comment: Yes.. This was the issue. It resolved with 0 0 */2 * * *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cheat sheet for Azure Function Cron Expresion

https://arminreiter.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/

In your case code may look like(Runs every 2 hours)

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 */2 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
```

I would also recommend to check runOnStartup and make sure that is set to **false**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python#configuration

Comment: Yes it is running every two hours, only when my Azure portal is open. As soon as I lose the same, the triggering is getting off.

Comment: I would recommend to check runOnStartup and make sure that is set to false
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python#configuration

Comment: Yes...the issue was with the corn expression only.